# How do I print all but the Nth to last line in sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting

- I'd like to do the complement / "opposite" of

  ```
  sed 13q;d <file.txt
  ```

  More generally, is it possible to do this sort of
  complement/inverse/opposite in `sed`? Or only for regexes?
- How do I print all but the third-to-last line?. Does this
  require two `tac`'s and counting forward in `sed`? Or is there a way
  to get `sed` itself to count from the back?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Part 1

Simply `d`elete the 13th line:

```
sed '13d' <file.txt
```

And a general way to do the complement of the above is:

```
sed '13!d' <file.txt
```

#### Part 2

Because it can be done:

```
sed -n ':a;${P;q};N;4,$D;ba' <file.txt
```

Note the `4` is one more than the number you require.  So if you wanted the last-10th line, this would be `11`.

Testing with `seq`:

```
$ seq 100 | sed -n ':a;${P;q};N;4,$D;ba'
98
$
```

#### Attempted explanation

```
:a        # define label a
${        # match the last line
    P     # print the first line of the pattern space
    q     # quit
}
N         # match all lines: append the next line to the pattern
4,${      # match the range of lines 4 to the end of the file
    D     # delete the first line of the pattern space
}
ba        # match all lines: jump back to label a
```

---

Glenn Jackman's valuable addition:

That was "only the Nth line". Here is "all BUT the Nth line":

```
sed -n ':a;${s/^[^\n]*\n//;p;q};N;4,${P;D};ba'
```

works with GNU sed, the `\n` sequence may not work with other seds.

---

I tried this with BSD sed (OSX) and found it didn't quite work in the form above.  The issues appear to be:

1. `;` used to separate lines seems to generally work, but doesn't work after a label
2. BSD sed appears to require `;` after the last command in a one-line `{}` command group, whereas GNU sed does not
3. `\n` can generally be used within the regular expression, but apparently not within a `[]` bracket expression.  So to exclude newlines, we can use something like `[[:alnum:][:punct:][:graph:][:blank:]]` instead, though this may exclude other characters (specifically other control characters).

So this is an attempt at a more platform independent version:

```
sed -n ':a
${s/^[[:alnum:][:punct:][:graph:][:blank:]]*\n//p;q;};N;4,${P;D;};ba'
```

This appears to work under OSX and Ubuntu.

Comment: @jimmij The other answers about related questions in the SE network suggest that a `head`/`tail` solution is much slower than a `sed` solution. Thanks though.

Comment: @isomorphismes no program can know the number of lines in a file unless it goes through the whole file. There's no way around that. The only way to count from the bottom is to either reverse the file and count from the top or to parse it twice. So head/tail are going to be pretty much as fast as it gets.

Comment: @isomorphismes ... because they (`head`/`tail`) are optimized for doing what they do.

Comment: @isomorphismes - edited with all parts you need

Comment: Nice! I had to change my answer, since I somehow expected it to be more complicated. :)

Comment: @isomorphismes and here you can also see, why it is going to be much less efficient (speed, memory) than `tail` which can only store n last lines it encountered without any data being moved around and **stored**.

Comment: Oh my gracious. Thanks @DigitalTrauma! I can see why even though these seemed related to me, they're actually very very different in magnitude of complexity .... `tac` it is!